# jQuery script not functioning in IE9 or Chrome (works in FireFox)

Tags: jquery, firefox, google-chrome, internet-explorer-9

Attempting to get jQuery to execute a method upon loading a page fails for Chrome and IE9. The following attempts to execute a method have been tried to no avail:

```
(function($) { $(document).ready(function(){
slideShow(7500); }); })(jQuery);

$(document).bind("ready", function() { slideShow(7500); })

$(window).load(function() {slideShow(7500);});
alert(typeof $);
```

Please note: the last of these attempts to execute jQuery failed to even produce an alert in Chrome and IE9.

Also, placing these scripts at the end of the document did not solve the problem. Doing so produced a blank page. All versions of the script listed above work in FireFox.

Comment: Which JQuery version are you using? Does it throw any error?

Comment: You need to look in the IE or Chrome debug consoles and see what errors are being reported - not much we can do here.  The alert may not fire if a previous error in the same script already aborted execution.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    slideShow(7500); 
}
```

after you include jquery?

Answer (score 0):

```
(function($) { $(document).ready(function(){
slideShow(7500); }); })(jQuery);
```

seems a bit convoluted (as jessica points out) but should still work. I suspect your `slideShow()` function is the cuplrit.

Comment: I feel like the alert would at least fire?